# How to use nth-child/type-of to change background colour based on user input?

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors, user-defined-functions

I am trying to change the background of table cells based on the user input.

If the user inputs 3 hours, and the time at 10. Then I need to change the background of table cells 7-8, 8-9, 9-10 to display this range.

Here is the HTML:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th id="car">Car</th>
   <th id="7">7 - 8</th>
   <th id="8">8 - 9</th>
   <th id="9">9 - 10</th>
   <th id="10">10 - 11</th>
   <th id="11">11- 12</th>
   <th id="12">12 -13</th>
   <th id="13">13 - 14</th>
   <th id="14">14 - 15</th>
   <th id="15">15 - 16</th>
   <th id="16">16 - 17</th>
   <th id="exit_miles">Exit Miles</th>                            
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr id="car-1-test">
   <td id="car-1">Car 1</td>
   <td id="car-1-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-11" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-12" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-14" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-15" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-16" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
   <td id="car-1-exit-miles">60</td>
</tr>
```

What I have so far..

```
// Check how many hours are needed for charge 

function checkHours(){
  var lhours = $("#car-1-charge-needed").text();
  var ltime = $("#car-1-lt")
    $("#car-1-test > td:nth-child("+ ltime - lhours.val +")").css("background-colour", "blue");
}

// Generate time table 

$('#generate-time-table').click(function() {
 checkHours();
})
```

and here is the fiddle with the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/bv5jct7n/6/

Fiddle updated.

To clarify, the outcome of the user input indicates how many hours need to be set and the time they are leaving. I need to show in the table these hours are blocked out before the leave time.

EDIT** Updated JS to show correct variables. Thanks Andreas.

I actually think this may be the wrong approach. I am thinking maybe it is better if I could toggle the class from not charging, to charging, based off of the user input ( hours needed for charge, and time leaving) rather then trying the nth- child approach. Am still unsure how I can achieve this, or it nth-child/type-of is how I would achieve this. Any advice is most welcome.

```
$(".generate").click(function() {
  var lvalue = Number(document.getElementById('time-input').value);
  var hoursneeded = document.getElementById('car-1-charge-needed').textContent;
  var timeTd = $('table_id_2 td[id$="-' + lvalue + '"]'),
      previousTds = timeTd.prevAll().slice(0, -1),
      numberOfHours = hoursneeded;
  $("table_id_2 td").removeClass("blocked");
  previousTds.slice(0, numberOfHours)
             .addClass("blocked");
             console.log(hoursneeded);
});
```

Code updated now I think there are no errors, but I am still not getting the desired result.

Comment: Its meant to take the value from lhours (come from user input) and assign it to the td cell with that number value. I.e user input = 8, it starts at the cell number 8 then goes back the amount of hours from the "hours needed" user input. I can see it's a duplicate which isn't right. Thank you, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix of the [ends with (`$=`) selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), [`.prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) for this

First find the `<td>` whose id ends with the given time:

```
var timeTd = $('table td[id$="-' + time + '"]')
```

Then grab all `<td>` elements before that (`.prevAll()`) and remove the first cell (the name of the car) with `.slice()`

```
var previousTds = timeTd.prevAll().slice(0, -1); /* the tds are in reverse order, hence the (0, -1) range */
```

We now have to select the number of elements we want to "block" with another `.slice()` call

```
var tdsToBlock = previousTds.slice(0, numberOfHours);
```

Working example:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var timeTd = $('table td[id$="-' + this.value + '"]'),
      previousTds = timeTd.prevAll().slice(0, -1),
      numberOfHours = 2;

  $("table td").removeClass("blocked");

  previousTds.slice(0, numberOfHours)
             .addClass("blocked");
})
```

```css
.blocked {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="car">Car</th>
      <th id="7">7 - 8</th>
      <th id="8">8 - 9</th>
      <th id="9">9 - 10</th>
      <th id="10">10 - 11</th>
      <th id="exit_miles">Exit Miles</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="car-1-test">
      <td id="car-1">Car 1</td>
      <td id="car-1-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
      <td id="car-1-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
      <td id="car-1-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
      <td id="car-1-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
      <td id="car-1-exit-miles">60</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that to me. It makes sense what you have said. I am going to try and take what you said an implement it in to my code now. Will let you know how it goes. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry I have implemented the code, but when i click the generate button it doesn't work. I must of miss understood something, sorry.

Comment: I've edited the question with the most up to date code using your snippet.

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ is the most useless error description that ever existed ;) There isn't a [mcve] in your question to work with. And trying to adapt the full example on jsfiddle is out ot scope for me.

Comment: Lol sorry, my bad. Still a noob on Stack. Ok so the generate time table button, when clicked, doesn't seem to do anything. I changed "  $("select").on("change", function() {" to "  $('#generate-time-table').click(function() { " hoping to replicate what the snippet does. When I check the console, it doesn't show any errors though. I also added in the variable value "lvalue". I will try to find out more to explain better.

Comment: If you only change `.on("change", ...` to `.on("click", ...` then `this.value` would be the content of the `value` attribute of the clicked button. You have to replace `this.value` with whatever defines the time slot (`10` in your example). The same for `numberOfHours` (which would be the `3` hours in your example).

Comment: Ahh right, okok thank you, I will try that now. Thank you.

Comment: Still playing around with it, also i forgot to update the id's which am doing now. Have updated the others you mentioned, still playing to get it to work like it does in the snippet.

Comment: To clarify, should the td slice range "var previousTds = timeTd.prevAll().slice(0, -1);" the range be for all of the potenital outcomes. i.e slice(9, -1)? Sorry I am just getting a bit confused and going through the answer step by step.

Comment: No. The `.slice(0, -1)` just removes the "first" cell which has the "name" of the car. It's `0, -1` because the cells are in reverse order. The one with the "name" is the last in the selection, hence we take all elements from index zero to `length - 1` which can be expressed as `-1` (check the documentation for `.slice()`)

Comment: Right, thank you for explaining, will check the documentation now.

Comment: So I have worked out that the variable hoursneeded is spitting out NaN, I am now looking in to why and how to fix.

Comment: I got it working! You won't believe this, but i forgot to add a "#" when i changed the table I.D.... now it works lol Thank you so much for your patience and help with this. I really appreciate it :D

Comment: Hmm I have one small bug, it goes to car 6 row, not car 1, but i think I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: `$('table td[id$="-' + numberToLookFor + '"]')` selects every `<td>` whose id ends with `-<numberToLookFor>`. If there are multiple cars then there will be multiple `<td>` that end with the same number. If you need a specific car then replace the selector with a more specific one.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I am working with now i.e $('table td[id$="("#car-1" - ' + numberToLookFor + '"]')

Comment: Have a look at how CSS selectors work. Yours is not even valid. Also ids are unique so combining them in another selector if you're only looking for that id element is unnecessary work. And if you have the complete id you don't need a _"ends with"_ selector...

Comment: The issue is, i need the first part of the i.d i.e car-1 then, the last bit is determined by the lvalue variable. Looking on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#:~:text=A%20CSS%20selector%20is%20the,the%20rule%20applied%20to%20them. now.